# Regex to match subdomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the following so far:

```
^((http[s]?|ftp):\/\/)(([^.:\/\s]*)[\.]([^:\/\s]+))(:([^\/]*))?(((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?)?$
```

Been testing against these:

```
https://www.google.com.ar:8080/dir/1/2/search.html?arg=0-a&arg1=1-b&arg3-c#hash 
https://google.com.ar:8080/dir/1/2/search.html?arg=0-a&arg1=1-b&arg3-c#hash 
https://google.com:8080/dir/1/2/search.html?arg=0-a&arg1=1-b&arg3-c#hash 
http://www.foo.com
http://www.foo.com/
http://blog.foo.com/
http://blog.foo.com.ar/
http://foo.com
http://blog.foo.com
http://foo.com.ar
```

I'm using the following tool to test the regexes: [regex tester](http://www.regextester.com/)

So far I've been able to yield the following groups:

1. full protocol
2. reduced protocol
3. full domain name
4. *subdomain?*
5. top level domain
6. port
7. port number
8. rest of the url
9. rest of the "directory"
10. no idea how to drop this group
11. page name
12. argument string
13. argument string
14. hash tag
15. hash tag

I will be using this regex to change the subdomain for my application for cross-domain redirect hyperlinks.

Using `Request.Url` as a parameter, I want to redirect from

`http://example.com` or `http://www.example.com` to `http://blog.example.com`

How can I achieve this?

I can't really tell what, if any, the current subdomain ( either nothing, www, blog, or forum, for instance) actually is...

What would be the best way to make this replacement?

What I actually need is some way to find out what the top level domain is. in either `http://www.example.com`, `http://blog.example.com`, or `http://example.com` I want to get `example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best way to make this replacement?

This may not be the answer you're looking for... but IMO the best way would be to make use of the `System.Uri` class.

The Uri class will easily extract the `Host` for you - and you can then `split` the host on "." delimiter - that should easily give you access to the current subdomain.

---

This is just my opinion - and its especially formed because I find it hard to maintain regex code like `^((http[s]?|ftp):\/\/)(([^.:\/\s]*)[\.]([^:\/\s]+))(:([^\/]*))?(((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?)?$`

Comment: This won't help because host includes the www part, and it doesn't when you connect without specifying www explicitly

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying. For any Uri, Host should include whatever the url contains in the host part - e.g. for "http://sub1.example.com/default.html", then Host is `sub1.example.com`

Comment: I just want some way to find out what the top level domain is. in either `http://www.example.com`, `http://blog.example.com`, or `http://example.com` I want to get `example.com`.

Comment: So use "System.Uri" to get to "blog.example.com", then use string.split on that? (Sorry - really don't understand the problem!)

Comment: The fact that if the url is just `http://example.com` there isn't a subdomain part at all. That's the problem

Comment: Still not sure what you are looking for - (and technically example is a subdomain of com in example.com - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name)

Comment: Likewise I don't quite understand the question but using System.Uri would simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Uri class to parse the strings.  There are many properties available in addition to Segments:

```
Uri MyUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com.ar:8080/dir/1/2/search.html?arg=0-a&arg1=1-b&arg3-c#hash");

foreach (String Segment in MyUri.Segments)
    Response.Write(Segment + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider whether usage of a RegEx is really needed in this case;

- I think extracting the top level domain from an URL is quite simple; in case of "http://www.example.com/?blah=111" you can simply take the part before the 3rd slash and perform a String.Split('.') and concat the last two array items. In case of "http://www.example.com", even easier.

  - Regex-patterns are very error-prone and quite hard to maintain and according to me you won't get any advantage of it. I recommend you to get rid off the Regex. Perhaps the result will be 2 - 3 more lines of code, but it will work, your code will be much better readable and easier to understand.

Comment: and if the top-level domain isn't example.com but example.co.uk, for instance?

Comment: Therefore the 2-3 extra lines of code :) In domains such as "domain.com.tw" or "domain.co.uk"; to be compatible with those urls, you should test the last but one array item for a "reserved" domain suffix such as "com" or "co" and there are just few to check for. In that case you take the last three array items as top level domain. Easy isn't?